# Can I make a Xaml one liner?

Tags: wpf, xaml

lamp xamlI'm using the structure below a lot of times in DataTemplates to make little 'lamps' light up.

Could I put it in a ContentPresenter or DataTemplate or anything like it to reduce the code to one line?

The 'test' value is hardcoded in xaml for every lamp. I get a binding value with a Dictionary'<'string, Signal> called Signals.

I can't use a MultiBinding with a Converter since it uses just as many lines. Any ideas to make this a one liner in xaml?

```
<StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding Signals[test].tooltip}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Signals[test].lampvalue}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenLampPresenter}" />
    <TextBlock Text="test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It would be perfect if the example below was in fact a legal statement in xaml. I still want both the signal from my dictionary and the hardcoded value:

```
Content="{Binding Path=Signals[test], StringFormat='{0} test'}".
```

The case is that I have more than 100 of lamps like in the little image. And the state of the lamp is saved in the dictionary. If the lamp is not found in the dictionary it means that it is not wired up in the configuration (or in the physical controller). It still needs the little text I0 to identify it.  [image: Green Lamp] If I dont have the harcdcoded 'IO' value to name the lamp only a green will show. And in the physical controller the 'IO' value is always present.

So please do suggest a valid solution containing both the values: Signal[test] and 'test' in one line :-)

Comment: If you're literally just trying to condense the two things, `Content="{Binding Path=Signals[test].lampvalue, StringFormat='{0} test'}"` set as comment instead of answer because I havent had coffee yet and wasnt sure.

Comment: I edited my question to describe my problem more precisely

Comment: Umm, that is a "legal" statement in xaml.

Comment: Ok, Visual Studio accepted it when adding {} inside the '':
     Content="{Binding Path=Signals[test].lampvalue, StringFormat='{}{0} test'}".
But what does the statement mean? Does this mean that I have a multibinding with two values? How do I use the two parameters inside my ContentPresenter? Or should I use a Converter?

Comment: Ok, I get. I create a string composing the lampvalue with the constant 'text'. But then the tooltip value is still missing. Can you use StringFormat to combine two variables with the constant value?

Comment: You can do MultiBinding, and you could do the same in your own specified tooltip.

Comment: Still in a one-liner?

Comment: If you can do the StringFormat for your Content, you can do the same with your Tooltip. At least I know you can in SL, WPF I don't recall if you have to break it out like <ToolTip>blah</ToolTip> or not. Haven't messed with WPF in awhile so am a little rusty.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but i think it should work.

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="greenLampTemplate">
  <StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding tooltip}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding lampvalue}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenLampPresenter}" />
    <TextBlock Text="test"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Using DataTemplate:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Signals[test]}" 
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource greenLampTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: If I havn't been precise enough: You have to put the hardcoded value 'test' into the one line too!

Comment: That is in the DataTemplate he has here.

Comment: @bitestar i have changed the templates

Comment: I just added a more precise specification in the original question. I still need the value 'test' to a part of the one liner

Comment: and not a part of the new DataTemplate